# How do I change a Gatsby post title site wide?

Tags: gatsby

I want my post titles to be title case.

1. It must be site wide (not just in places like `<Helmet>`. I want to avoid duplication and the possibility of missing a reference.
2. I don't want to go back to my posts and update each one that isn't title case.

Is there a way to override frontmatter? I tried changing it in `gatsby-node.js` but I am not sure where to add/change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that I think is a hack. The frontmatter can be overridden during the creation of a node `onCreateNode` by updating the node before it is pushed to the nodes array. I leverage the `postNodes` array (a global array to the gatsby-node scope) to create my blog pages.

```
createNodeField({ node, name: "slug", value: slug })
node.frontmatter.title = _.startCase(_.toLower(node.frontmatter.title))
postNodes.push(node)
```

Then when the post pages are created `exports.createPages`, the `postNodes` are used which have the updated values.

```
    let idx = 0;
    postNodes.map(node => {
      let previous = idx - 1 < 0 ? postNodes[postNodes.length - 1] : postNodes[idx - 1]
      let next = idx + 1 >= postNodes.length ? postNodes[0] : postNodes[idx + 1]

      createPage({
        path: node.fields.slug,
        component: postPage,
        context: {
          slug: node.fields.slug,
          prev: previous.fields.slug,
          next: next.fields.slug
        }
      })
      idx += 1;
    })
```

***Note*** Prev and next wasn't working at the time of writing that code so it needs to be revised.

Comment: Hi @cbillowes, could you share more of your `onCreateNode`? What is `postNodes` and where does it come from?

Comment: It's a global array in `gatsby-node.js` that is called in `addSiblingNodes` which I make use of in `createPages` because prev and next wasn't working at that time.

It's a hack which is why I haven't marked my answer as the answer. There must be a cleaner and more efficient way of doing this. I'll update my answer to have more code.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to need to modify the way `gatsby-transformer-remark` modify frontmatter, and it reminded me of this question. The way you've done it is perfectly fine imo, I just want to provide another option. Here's how you can override frontmatter:

Internally, `gatsby-transformer-remark` use [`graymatter`](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gray-matter) to parse markdown's frontmatter (treating md as yaml). We can modify graymatter's default parser behavior to directly override frontmatter.

```
// should come with `gatsby-transformer-remark` by default
// if it's missing, install it `yarn add js-yaml`
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

const customParser = (str) => {
  const result = yaml.safeLoad(str);

  // modify `title`. In Gatsby, `title` is guaranteed to exist,
  // but you might want to add a check for other properties.
  if (result.title) {
    result.title = result.title.toUpperCase();
  }
  return result;
}
```

And then pass it into `gatsby-transformer-remark` like

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
+   engines: {
+     yaml: customParser,
+   },
    plugins: [
      ...
    ],
  },
},
```

Gatsby query results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "markdownRemark": {
      "frontmatter": {
        "title": "I AM CAPITALIZED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```